# Problem with Ubuntu interface

Tags: interface

Yesterday I upgraded the Ubuntu system to the terminal and after restarting the system a black screen appears and nothing can be run. Can I fix the system or even drag files?
System version: ubuntu 17.10.1
 And act on it as a basic computer system with Windows.

Comment: what the kernel are your using sir?

Comment: kernel Linux ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 17.10 is **EOL**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to copy my files through USB files in the installation of Ubuntu and after take off I chose to try Ubuntu and entered the file and I was able to drag my files and put them in another USB ..

[image]